# preventing sequelize making all columns nullable by default

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

im new to sequelize , i've noticed it makes all the columns nullable by default unless it's told otherwise in the migration

```
  column_name: {
    allowNull: false,
  },
```

i prefer it other way around , columns shouldn't be nullable unless they've been defined like that ! right now if i forget to set a value for a column it's just setting it to null which can be very problematic ... and i dont want to put  `allowNull: false` in every single migration file

is there any way to disable this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not yet : a user suggested using `false` by default for `allowNull`, a maintainer seem to be open to this idea, and also would like to allow users to choose.

([`sequelize/sequelize#14260`](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/14260))

Comment: thanx , this is so dumb i thought maybe im missing something